# How can I calculate RC circuit impedance and phase difference in parallel?

Tags: impedance, parallel, phase-shift, esr

Most of articles on the web, define capacitor as ideal capacitor. I want calculate impedance and phase difference of this circuit  with capacitor ESR.

For example :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvNsc0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Above image shows formula to calculate ideal RC circuit. If I have ESR in capacitor, in this case, how does the formula change?

Comment: Well, nobody's stopping you.  Where are you stuck?  Maybe redraw the circuit with the capacitor ESR shown explicitly, and start there.

Comment: What is the circuit representing?

Comment: You model the ESR as a resistance in series with the capacitor, then proceed as shown in your diagram with one parallel branch being the sum of the resistance and capacitive impedance.